# Chemical reaction scheme with loop

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'm trying to produce the scheme in the figure on latex, so far my attempts are abortive.
I've added here what I have so far using the `chemfig` package:

[image]

```
\schemestart
 A \arrow{->[$k_{on}$]} 
 B \arrow{->[$k_{c}$]}
 C
  \arrow(C---){->[$k_{d}$]}[30,1.75] D
 \arrow(@C---){->[$k_{d}^{'}$]}[-30,1.75] E
 \arrow{<=>[*{0} $k_{a}^{}$][*{0} $k_{a}^{'}$]}[90,1.85]
\schemestop
```

Comment: `\arrow(C---)` has a `-` too much. It should be `\arrow(C--)`.

Comment: @clemens, thanks, I'm just missing to arrows back to A now

Comment: Do the outer arrows need to have edges or may they go directly?

Comment: @clemens, yes they do...or any other type of arrow that is not direct with an angle, they can also be rounded

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new arrow type as explained in section 11 of part IV of the `chemfig` manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\definearrow{3}{-|>}{%
  \CF@arrow@shift@nodes{#3}%
  \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF@arrow@current@style,-CF]
    (\CF@arrow@start@node) -| (\CF@arrow@end@node)
    node[midway] (arrow@middle){} ;%
  \CF@arrow@display@label
    {#1}{0.5}{+}{\CF@arrow@start@node}
    {#2}{0.5}{-}{arrow@middle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \schemedebug{true}
\schemestart
  A \arrow(A--){->[$k_{on}$]} 
  B \arrow{->[$k_{c}$]}
  C \arrow(C--D){->[$k_{d}$]}[30,1.75] D
  \arrow(@C--E){->[$k_{d}^{'}$]}[-30,1.75] E
  \arrow(@E--@D){<=>[*{0} $k_{a}^{}$][*{0} $k_{a}^{'}$]}
  \arrow(@E--@A){-|>}
  \arrow(@D--@A){-|>}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

For reasons I don't understand the arrows don't quite end at node `A` but a little bit beside it. And if one adds an anchor (`\arrow(@E--@A.south){-|>}`) the node gets shifted instead of the arrow tip. I suspect that there's a bug when an arrow connects two nodes with the `(@node1--@node2)` syntax but I'm not sure… probably a question for Christian, the author of `chemfig`.

Comment: its not bad, however the arrow does not end at node A as you mentioned and if I add a rate k above the arrow it is far from it and with an angle.

Comment: @jarhead the label placement should work now

Comment: yes, thanks, I still did not resolve the arrow issue

Comment: @jarhead I know.